# Purging all old CMFEditions versions

Tags: plone

We have big huge site which database should be prepared for development copies.

How one can remove all old history versions of all content items? This way we could greatly reduce the size of data needed to transfer to developer computers.

Plone 4.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Go to portal_purgepolicy and set the number to some number (I usually use '3' to keep at least some history).
2. Run the following script:

   ```
   from DateTime import DateTime
   from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName
   from Products.CMFEditions.utilities import dereference


   policy = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_purgepolicy')
   catalog = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_catalog')

   for count, brain in enumerate(catalog()):
       obj = brain.getObject()

       # only purge old content
       if obj.created() < (DateTime() - 30):
           obj, history_id = dereference(obj)
           policy.beforeSaveHook(history_id, obj)
           print 'purged object ' + obj.absolute_url_path()
   ```

Comment: Will merge with this after testing: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hosting/zope.html#creating-a-cleaned-data-drop

Comment: It would be nice to add this utility to CMFEditions and expose it in the ZMI somewhere.

Comment: This trick really helped me in old Plone installation where versioning was abused

I created a cript that helped me cleaning: https://github.com/RedTurtle/plone_clean_history

Comment: keul: how do remove all content with that script (keep history = 0 does nothing)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Zero probably means 'no restriction'. As DateTime is used, the oldest possible date to set, would be January 1, 1901, hth.

Answer (score 4):

I've details for Plone 3 (but note that I know that this is changed a little on Plone 4).

In Plone 3.3 histories are all stored inside the portal_historiesstorage/repo object. There you have a _shadowStorage subobject.

I found that if you delete this persistent object, it's created from scratch when needed.

Hope this help in some way

Answer (score 2):

Here are instructions to delete _shadowStorage, as keul hints above:

Start ZEO client in debug mode:

```
  bin/client1 debug
```

Then:

```py
  del app.yoursiteid.portal_historiesstorage._shadowStorage
  import transaction ; transaction.commit()
```

No warranty. No idea what it is deleting. Apparently you get rid of all histories.

Comment: according to Alec Mitchell, getting rid of the shadow storage just erases metadata and if you need to erase entries in the storage repository you have to do some other stuff; see https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFEditions/issues/28#issuecomment-113591175 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found (in what was probably a case of RTFM on my case, but anyway) that opening up the Zope site (http://localhost:8080/ say) directly, and navigating as follows:

1. manage page
2. "Control Panel"
3. "database"
4. "Main"

led me to a page which offered to "pack" the database and remove all history older than X days old.  This worked like a treat!

Comment: But this does not remove the CMFEdition entries. This only packs the database. There are two different kinds of histories: the CMFEdition based ones as asked initial here - and the ZODB History, which you are clearing with the "Pack" link.