# Packing Plone data

Tags: plone, versioning, history, undo

I am new to Plone and trying to learn how to setup and maintain a server. I realize I need to develop a schedule for packing the data. Right now I am just trying to test this using the pack function in the Zope control panel and also the command line (bin/zeopack).

I know in practice I should leave a week's worth of history, but if I pack to 0 days shouldn't I see all edit history disappear? I am not seeing this happen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be confusing the "undo" history with the version history. Packing the database gets rid of old, unused data. That eliminates your ability to undo older transactions.

Version history is not the same. Version history is not considered unused data, and is not eliminated in packs.

If you don't want edit history, turn off versioning.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683466/purging-all-old-cmfeditions-versions for how to remove old version history.

Comment: To clarify a bit, I was confused in exactly what packing the data accomplished. I was expecting it to clear out the version history of pages on the website, but when I saw the version history still there after packing I was confused. What this actually does is trim your ability to roll the site back to a previous version. You can see all site edits at http://your.plone.url/undo_form where you have a chance to undo any edit to your site, even retrieving things that have been deleted. Packing shortens this history, saving space on your server.

Comment: @user1678639 packing packs away previous transactions. It's a side-effect that rolling back transactions can SOMETIMES function similarly to an undo history, but it is not an undo history as commonly understood. I.e. seemingly unrelated objects A and B may have been changed in the same transaction; rolling back the transaction reverts both of them.