# I can't packing my Data.fs, Because too large more than 500GB

Tags: plone, zope, zodb

Unfortunately, I have a more than 500GB ZODB, Data.fs in my Plone site(Plone 5.05)
So, I have no way to use bin/zeopack to packing it,
Seriously affecting performance
What should I do ?

Comment: Wow... how the hell did you do this??? Did you somehow disable the blob storage? I got also Plone Sites with huge load of data, but the main part is in the blob directory. Since you're asking this you have a physical server right? The only solution I know, is to attach a 2TB USB drive and move the filestorage to the attached disk and run `pack`.

Comment: btw. You should also enables some monitoring services, to never run again in this situation ;-)

Comment: Yes, I really have available hdd space over 1.2TB (1.8 TB hdd, and 512GB in Data.fs), but still fail.

Comment: And, I don't disable blob storage. In this site, only has few blob files( like images, or files ), but have more than a million dexterity's content. with depth of 6 layers (ex. http://example.com/data/2016/11/01/recent/content)

Comment: nevertheless I guess there's a lot of history stored. Do you have just "no space left on device"? Did you try to set keep-history to 0?

Comment: If this is an history problem, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683466/purging-all-old-cmfeditions-versions/9684591#9684591 and https://github.com/RedTurtle/redturtle.historymanager

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're running out of space on the volume containing your data.

First, try turning off `pack-keep-old` in your zeoserver settings:

```
[zeoserver]
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver
...
pack-keep-old false
```

This will disable the creation of a .old copy of the Data.fs file and matching blobs. That may allow you to complete your pack.

Alternatively, create a matching Zope/Plone install on a separate machine or volume with more storage and copy over the data files. Run zeopack there. Copy the now-packed storage back.